# Why am I getting the error "using uninitialized memory 'i'" and "uninitialized local variable 'i' used" when trying to make i = i*i

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, increment

I am new to C++ and was testing out `while` loops and the sheer speed of C++ and its toll on my CPU and I got the following errors:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Warning C6001 Using uninitialized memory 'i'
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error 4700 uninitialized local variable 'i' used
```

I have no idea how to read an error message and haven't even encountered initializing in C++ yet so I don't have any clue about what to do.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    long long i = 0;
    while (i < 10000000000000000) {
        long long i = i*i;
        cout << i ;
    }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two *different and distinct and totally unrelated* variables both named `i`. Why don't you just *print the result* of `i * i` instead of defining a new variable by that name?

Comment: `long long i = i*i;` What is the value of `i`, when you are multiplying it? The fact, that there's a variable, by the same name, in the above scope, changes nothing, since it is shadowed by this declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the body of the while loop

```
while (i < 10000000000000000) {
    long long i = i*i;
    cout << i ;
}
```

you declared the variable `i` that is not initialized and has an indeterminate value and you are trying to use this indeterminate value to initialize the variable itself.

That is in this declaration

```
    long long i = i*i;
```

in the initializer there is used the same declared variable i that hides the declaration of the variable with the same name that appears before the loop

Substitute the declaration for the statement

```
   i = i*i;
```

But initially you should set the variable i to some value unequal to 0 for example to 10.

```
long long i = 10;
```

Otherwise the result of the expression `i * i` always will be equal to 0.

Something like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long i = 10;
    while (i < 10'000'000'000'000'000) {
        i = i*i;
        cout << i ;
    }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Though you should be caution selecting the initial value of the variable `i` because an overflow can occur in the expression `i * i` and you can get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

`long long i = i * i;` shadows the `long long i = 0;` declared outside the while loop. It's a totally separate variable and you're attempting to initialize it to its own value squared. If you want to use the variable `i` you declared outside the loop, drop the redeclaration:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long i = 0;
    while (i < 10000000000000000) {
        i = i*i;
        cout << i ;
    }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this will be an endless loop that just prints `0` over and over again.

Comment: Thank you and the 0 part I dont know what i was thinking